# Missing file from documentation generated with phpDocumentor: No summary was found for this file on line 0

Tags: symfony, phpdoc, docblocks

The documentation for all other files are being generated, but for src/Pagination/Paginator.php, it isn't. This is a Symfony 4 application.

The related error is:

```
error: Line 0: No summary was found for this file
```

No summary? That's wrong. The file doesn't seem different in structure from the others. A DocBlock for the file and a DocBlock for each class. Take a look:

```
<?php

/**
 * This file is part of DevDungeon.
 *
 * Copyright 2019 <my_name>.
 *
 * DevDungeon is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
 * along with DevDungeon.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

namespace App\Pagination;

use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder as DoctrineQueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\CountWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as DoctrinePaginator;

/**
 * This class defines the pagination logic.
 */
class Paginator
{
    /**
     * @var int The number of items displayed on a single page
     */
    private const PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    (...)
```

When navigating through the generated documentation, the Paginator class is just missing. Gone. What is happening here?

I'm using the PHAR file on a Windows system. It is located at the root of the project, just outside src/. GraphViz was manually installed later.

This is the command I use:

```
php phpDocumentor.phar -d src/ -t docs/
```

And this is the output:

```
Collecting files .. OK
Initializing parser .. OK
Parsing files
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Controller\BlogController.php

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33
  No summary for method __construct()
  No summary for property $session
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Entity\Post.php
Parse Error: Syntax error, unexpected '?' on line 91  No summary was found for t
his file
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Form\PostType.php

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33
  No summary for method __construct()
  No summary for method buildForm()
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Kernel.php
Parse Error: Syntax error, unexpected T_CONST, expecting T_FUNCTION on line 35
No summary was found for this file
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Migrations\Version20190724140200.php

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33
  No summary for method getDescription()
  Argument $schema is missing from the Docblock of up
  No summary for method up()
  Argument $schema is missing from the Docblock of down
  No summary for method down()
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Migrations\Version20190727112301.php

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33
  No summary for method getDescription()
  Argument $schema is missing from the Docblock of up
  No summary for method up()
  Argument $schema is missing from the Docblock of down
  No summary for method down()
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Pagination\Paginator.php
Parse Error: Syntax error, unexpected T_CONST, expecting T_FUNCTION on line 35
No summary was found for this file
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Repository\PostRepository.php

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33
  No summary for method __construct()
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Validator\Constraints\ContainsSlug.php
  No summary for class \App\Validator\Constraints\ContainsSlug
Parsing C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\src\Validator\Constraints\ContainsSlugValidator
.php

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
ble in phar://C:/wamp64/www/devdungeon/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Plug
in/Core/Descriptor/Validator/Constraints/Functions/IsArgumentInDocBlockValidator
.php on line 33
Storing cache in "C:\wamp64\www\devdungeon\docs" .. OK
Load cache                                                         ..    0.006s
Preparing template "clean"                                         ..    0.007s
Preparing 17 transformations                                       ..    0.000s
Build "elements" index                                             ..    0.000s
Replace textual FQCNs with object aliases                          ..    0.001s
Resolve @link and @see tags in descriptions                        ..    0.001s
Enriches inline example tags with their sources                    ..    0.000s
Build "packages" index                                             ..    0.001s
Build "namespaces" index and add namespaces to "elements"          ..    0.000s
Collect all markers embedded in tags                               ..    0.000s
Transform analyzed project into artifacts                          ..
Applying 17 transformations
  Initialize writer "phpDocumentor\Plugin\Core\Transformer\Writer\FileIo"
  Initialize writer "phpDocumentor\Plugin\Twig\Writer\Twig"
  Initialize writer "phpDocumentor\Plugin\Graphs\Writer\Graph"
  Execute transformation using writer "FileIo"
  Execute transformation using writer "FileIo"
  Execute transformation using writer "FileIo"
  Execute transformation using writer "FileIo"
  Execute transformation using writer "FileIo"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
  Execute transformation using writer "Graph"
   0.543s
Analyze results and write report to log                            ..    0.000s
```

Comment: Now I see one possible reason: Parse Error: Syntax error, unexpected T_CONST, expecting T_FUNCTION on line 35. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason:

```
    /**
     * @var int The number of items displayed on a single page
     */
    private const PAGE_SIZE = 10;
```

The visibility declaration causes it. Removing `private` solves it.

This works:

```
    /**
     * @var int The number of items displayed on a single page
     */
    const PAGE_SIZE = 10;
```

A bug in phpDocumentor2?